# nginx not serving django static files

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm running my django project on amazon AMI machine and have problem with nginx serving static files. Project static folder path is `/home/user/projectname/app/static` and `nginx.conf` is

```
server {
listen       80;

location /static {
    alias /home/user/projectname/app/static;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

I tried to make collectstatic and change static location to `alias /home/user/static`; but it didn't help. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of your STATIC_URL? Do the files appear when you go directly to the URL? How are you referencing the files in your template?

Comment: "I have a problem serving static files" is too vague, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @DanielRoseman my static url is `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma i get 403 error and nginx can't load static files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you chown the home directory. This makes the static files accessible to nginx.

```
chown -R user:user /home 
chmod -R ug+r /home
```

Also, try running `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: If i run `collectstatic` and static files collected into `/home/user/static` should i change alias to `alias /home/user/static;`?

Comment: Chown didn't help me. Maybe i should put static files to another directory?

Answer (score 0):

please change the static directory into staticstorage

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location /static {
        alias /home/user/projectname/app/staticstorage;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
```

Comment: Only in nginx.conf or also change it in project folder?